# How to start nodejs and filebeat in same container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers, filebeat

I need to create a docker container with nodejs app and filebeat in same container. So filebeat will relay nodejs logs to my logstash server. I have created docker file and when i build the image it runs without error. But when i go inside container and see no files related to filebeat are created. NodeJS app runs as expected but filebeat is not working at all.

I have used the custom file given by filebeat https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/running-on-docker.html mentioned here

So can we run the nodeJS app and filebeat in same container? and if yes what i am doing wrong ?

Here is my docker file ---

```
# Test web app that returns the name of the host/pod/container servicing req
# Linux x64

FROM docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:7.13.4
COPY --chown=root:filebeat filebeat.yml /usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml

FROM node:current-alpine

LABEL org.opencontainers.image.title="Test node App" \
      org.opencontainers.image.description="Create logs for Opensearch" \
      org.opencontainers.image.authors="@user"

# Create directory in container image for app code
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

# Copy app code (.) to /usr/src/app in container image
COPY . /usr/src/app

# Set working directory context
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/logs

RUN touch /usr/src/app/logs/log.log

RUN touch /usr/src/app/logs/error_log.log

RUN ln -sf /proc/1/fd/1 /usr/src/app/logs/log.log

RUN ln -sf /proc/1/fd/1 /usr/src/app/logs/error_log.log

# Install dependencies from packages.json
RUN npm install

# Command for container to execute
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting at docker build ?

Comment: Don't do that. Spend a bit more time on the documentation where you will understand that you should run a single filebeat container. Then all other containers should log to stdout/stderr and start with the given labels so that filebeat parses their output.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some set up using the ELK container from github, removed logstash and added filebeat, you could take time and look at it hope, it helps, all it does is get all logs from all containers and emit them to kibana, make sure you change the port to you local machine port (192....)

https://github.com/kisakyamukama/ELF.git